# Row wise comparison of a matrix with a vector in R using vectorization

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, data-comparison

I want to compare each row of a matrix with a vector and generate an index of the first value from the *i*th row that is less than the *i*th value in the vector. The values in each row of the matrix are sorted in decreasing order. Since the number of rows is very large, I am looking for a vectorized solution and would want to avoid loops and apply function.

For example, if I want to compare the following matrix M and vector v, then the output should be (3,2,3,NA).

```
M = matrix(c(10.2,11.0,10,9.5,9.2,8.9,7.6,8.4,5.4,5.6,6.5,7.2),4,3)
M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 10.2  9.2  5.4
[2,] 11.0  8.9  5.6
[3,] 10.0  7.6  6.5
[4,]  9.5  8.4  7.2

v <- c(8.4,9.5,7.0,6.0)

The output should be (3,2,3,NA).
```

When I use 'which' function in R, it works for each row but is not vectorized.

```
which(M[2,]<v[2])[1]
2

which(M[3,]<v[3])[1]
3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectorized option would be `max.col`

```
max.col(M < v, 'first') *NA^!rowSums(M < v)
#[1]  3  2  3 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
apply(M < v, 1, function(x) which(x)[1])
# [1]  3  2  3 NA
```